# Batch file to edit line in ini file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, ini

I have an ini file that gets autogenerated.

Its second line is always:
`Version = W.XX.Y.ZZ`

Where `W` is the major version number, `XX` is the minor version, `Y` is the Build and `ZZ` is the Revision.

I need to open that ini file and edit that line using a batch file so that the build and revision numbers in that version get removed. Therefore, the line should end up like this:
`Version = W.XX`

The major number will always be one character and the minor number will always be two, therefore the entire string is 14 characters (inc spaces) long.

I was hoping that I could get the string that is `LEFT` 14 characters of that line and replace that line with that string.

Comment: The only way I know of doing this is to read in the whole file and write it back out line by line changing the desired line in the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "LEFT" syntax you're asking for is to use a variable substring expansion: `%var:~,14%`

The following code will perform a "LEFT 14" on every line that contains the string "Version"

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del output.ini
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.ini) do (
  set var=%%a
  if not {!var!}=={!var:Version=!} set var=!var:~,14!
  echo.!var! >> output.ini
)
endlocal
```

If there are other lines with the word "Version", you can also modify the loop to use a counter.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del output.ini
set counter=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.ini) do (
  set var=%%a
  set /a counter=!counter!+1
  if !counter! EQU 2 set var=!var:~,14!
  echo.!var! >> output.ini
)
endlocal
```

Note that in both cases, you might have to do more work if your file contains special symbols like |, <, or >

Comment: `set /a RyanBemroseVotes+=1` :)