# Batch - Find property in .ini file and increment

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a script that will update local policies on my computer. One of the steps is to edit Version value in gpt.ini. How to do this in batch ? I need to increment the value by 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to edit line in ini file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578896/batch-file-to-edit-line-in-ini-file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15413717/1683264 might help as well.

Comment: For incrementing values see `set /?` and look for the `/A` switch...